# For which real $r$ the Riemann-Liouville operator is bounded in space $L_2[0,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I proved that for $r > \frac{1}{2}$ the operator is bounded in the $L_2[0,1]$ space.

But I was not able to show the unbounded operator when $r\leq \frac{1}{2}$. My operator looks like this $(Ax)(t) = \frac{1}{t^r}\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)^{r-1}x(s) \,ds$.

I understand that it is necessary to take such a function $x(s)$ that the operator will be unbounded if $r\leq \frac{1}{2}$. But it became a problem for me to pick up such a function.

Comment: Shouldn't one of the inequalities about the value of $r$ be reversed?

Comment: For $r >\frac{1}{2}$ the operator is bounded, but it is possible for other r the operator is also bounded. Therefore, we need to show that for $r \geq \frac{1}{2}$, the operator is not bounded

Comment: If it is bounded for $r>1/2$, then for $r\geq 1/2$, the only remaining case is $r=1/2$, right? Or do you want to look at the cases $r<1/2$ as well?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I need to show that for $r \leq \frac {1}{2}$ the operator is not bounded